# when displaying text In d3.js, how to be specified at the position of the descender line instead of the baseline

Tags: d3.js, svg

In D3.JS, when displaying text, and tell me how to be specified at the position of the descender line instead of the baseline

---

**base line**

```
<svg width="100%" height="100" style="background-color:pink">
    <text x="0" y="0" font-size: 100px;">
        Prop
    </text>
</svg>
```

---

**descender line**

・However manually calculate the 85 in this code.

```
<svg width="100%" height="100" style="background-color:pink">
    <text x="0" y="85" font-size: 100px;">
        Prop
    </text>
</svg>
```

---

**Question**

・tell me how to specify the descender line at y = 0.

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/alignment-baseline